# Creating Runnable class with method that using callback post execution to UI main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, runnable

I have a question whether this code is correct. I have doubts whether background execution in Runnable class executes in run() method or also in constructor... Seems obvious that it is in run() but I would like to ensure my thoughts...

```
class Tracer implements Runnable {
  private Handler handler;
  private OnTracerCompletedListener callback;  

  Tracer(OnTracerCompletedListener callback) { 
       this.callback = callback;
       handler = new Handler(); // <--- is this on main UI thread?
  }

  @Override
  public void run() { 
      // do something on background thread 
      // after task completed notify invoker of Tracer using callback
      handler.post(new Runnable() { 
           @Override 
           public void run() { 
               if(callback != null) callback.onTracedCompleted(); 
           }
      }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the code in the constructor and the initializer, and the one in the method `run` is when and from what thread the code will be called.

So the code in the constructor of `Tracer` will be called immediately when the instance is created. It will be run in the thread of the caller. The method `run` will be run in the background (this I just assume since I don't know the architecture of your application).

So everything what should be done in the background should be done in the method `run`.

Comment: Ok so if I call Tracer from thread1 (usually UI main thread) and next method run is executing on thread2 then if I have Helper (android) instantiated in Tracer constructor then handler.post cause callback to be executed on thread1 (in this case UI main thread) ?

Comment: The short answer: Yes

The long answer: when you create the instance of Tracer in the UI thread, then the constructor of Tracer will be called on the UI thread. Then on the background thread the method `run` will be called. Then you create a new runnable with its method `run`. The `run` of the anonymous runnable will be called whenever the `hanlder.post` decides to run it. On Android the Handlers will run it on the UI thread.